# How to display fragment in android with background grayed out?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

When a RelativeLayout in an activity is clicked, it should open a fragment that shows a few checkboxes. The fragment should be in the center of the screen but should not cover the whole screen. The original contents activity should appear in the background but it should be grayed out. When I click 'OK' button in the fragment, the fragment should disappear and the original contents of the activity should appear normal (without graying out). I've tried writing a lot of code but what I get is completely different from what I have in mind. How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: Sounds like for the most part you are describing a `DialogFragment` - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: @MarkKeen thanks... I've never heard that before. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `DialogFragment` , see this thread: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html